# Umlaut and special characters in AS3 string

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm having issues using ó in a static string being used in an as3 URL link out.

code:
var url:String = "[http://www.blahblahblah.pl/show/atomnówki](http://www.blahblahblah.pl/show/atomn%C3%B3wki)";

output:
http://www.blahblahblah.pl/show/atomn%F3wki

I'm sure this is pretty basic but i'm having one of those days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String has been [percent-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  This is often done to URLs for the sake of systems that only support US-ASCII, but you also see it when transfering over email or as POST variabes (such as form submissions).

Top-level functions that undo percent-encoding include:

- [`decodeURI`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/package.html#decodeURI())
- [`decodeURIComponent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/package.html#decodeURIComponent())
- [`unescape`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/package.html#unescape())

Whichever is appropriate.